# What does CE_TXFULL mean? (Win32 Comm error flag)

Tags: windows, serial-port

Can someone explain to me what `CE_TXFULL` is about?

I understand that it's a problem when one of the RX queues runs over (HW FIFO, SW buffer).

I also understand that it could be a problem when the TX queue runs out of bytes to send. If the receiver has overly demanding timing restrictions that could be a problem.

But how can it ever be a problem if the TX queue is full? I mean `WriteFile` should gracefully time out in that case, and return the number of bytes that were written (which may be zero).

Thing is, I have to implement an interface that represents a simple UART by using the Windows `XxxCommXxx` functions. Now I need to know if I have to map `CE_TXFULL` to the "generic error" bit or not.

Cheers, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy :)

I should have checked MSDN online, not only the local version installed by VS 2005.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363180.aspx

```
The following values are not supported:
    CE_DNS 
    CE_IOE 
    CE_MODE 
    CE_OOP 
    CE_PTO 
    CE_TXFULL
```

No wonder I couldn't find any information about `CE_TXFULL` on the net.

So I guess `CE_TXFULL` doesn't mean anything, since it's not used, and I will never see it.